# Is there a way to prove that the 2-norm of a matrix is greater than the largest element?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I would like to prove

$$\max_{ij} |A_{ij}| \leq \| A \|_2$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hint: $A_{i,j}$ is an element of the vector $Ae_j$

Comment: Try $|A_{ij}|^2\leq \rVert A \lVert_2^2$.

Comment: @Exodd please see my comment on the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since the two-norm $\|A\|_2$ is defined as the maximum of some function over all vectors, all you need to do is find some vector for which that function is at least any given matrix entry; more concretely, you need some vector $x$ for which
$$\frac{|Ax|}{|x|}\geq A_{ij},$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the standard (Euclidean) norm on vectors. For scaling reasons, you might as well pick $x$ for which $|x|=1$; can you find some unit vector for which $A_{ij}$ becomes an entry of $Ax$?

Comment: Is the idea similar to the link below? I do not understand the idea of the dual, etc.. Is there a simpler way to explain what's going on here? I get the idea that |Aij| = |ei*Aej| but I do not understand the relation between this and norms. Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193722/proof-of-relation-between-maximum-element-and-induced-p-norm-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\|A\|_2$ usually refers to the [Frobenius norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), also called the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, defined to be
$$
\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2}.
$$
If this is what the OP has in mind, then the question is trivial since it is obvious that
$$
|a_{k,l}|^2 \leq \sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2,
$$
for every $k$ and $l$.

Most other matrix norms share this property, so it would be nice to know exactly which matrix norm is of interest to the OP.

Comment: Actually there are different meaning here. "2" may refer to the induced 2-norm, that is also called spectral or operator norm, or it may refer to the 2-Schatten norm, also called Frobenius norm

Comment: @Exodd, I suspect the most common meaning of $\|A\|_2$ is the Frobenius norm but you are right, the potential for misunderstanding is significant, as I acknowledged in my answer.  We can only hope the OP clarifies their intention so the question can be reopened.

Comment: Actually, the statement is true for both norms so...

Comment: Not only for these two, but also for virtually any norm considered in the literature!